# Voltage drop cable regulations

Tags: regulations

[image]

I've just started the electrical installation part of my engineering course and I'm clueless on how to solve this any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  We do not do homework without effort from you.  Clock is ticking.

Comment: I've looked at the table and at 11mV/A/m i don't see any correlation to how to calculate voltage drop

Comment: So you have 45m and you have to get there and comeback.  At 20A or 16A if they are going by code.

Comment: Do you know how to find the resistance per unit length?

Comment: is the answer 9.9V?

Comment: *is the answer 9.9V?*  Please update your post to show your work on how you arrived at that answer.

Comment: Check table F4(ii) to see if that's volt drop per metre there and back, or just volt drop per metre.  A 45m cable has 45m there and 45m back again.